Old man in a house, traps people, wheelchair on tracks, 80's?
This movie takes place in an old house, outside it is like a junk yard. The old man shots in a chair that is on tracks or something and he goes around the house. The people can't leave and ate trying to get away. It must be from the 80's or early 90's. Help? 
American, most likely. White actors. I've always thought that Tom Hanks was in it but I'm not certain. I'd recognize the old man with the blanket on his lap any day. I am just so bag at actor names...

Welcome to Movies & TV Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Possibly Nothing But Trouble from 1991, a bizarre horror comedy with Chevy Chase, Dan Aykroyd, John Candy and Demi Moore. Aykroyd plays an old, insane judge with an, er, unusual nose who lives in a junkyard and imprisons people in his house, often judging them to death. He's not a paraplegic, but he does appear on a couple of mechanized chairs and there are plenty of tracks there too (amusement rides, toy trains etc.). Aykroyd also directed, and I'm pretty sure the film was a big flop. Here's the trailer:




Yup, that's it! I went to bed last night thinking it was Dan Akroyd. Thanks! Now my brain can move on to more important things!
